# Overlay transparent video over an image with FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a transparent video, now I want to add an image in the transparent part of the video.
The below command helps to overlay image in video but it covers full part of the video and few portions of video become invisible. Anyone, please suggest a way to fix this?  Many thank in advance.

ffmpeg -i input.avi -i image.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=204:773:enable='between(t,0,5)'" output.avi

[image: Transparent video]

[image: Output video with image overlaps some part of the video as highlighted]

Comment: You have to pad the image to the same size of the video and then overlay the video on top of the padded image.

Comment: @Gyan You mean create a same size of image as video has and overlap video on image? In this case only partial portion of image is visible?